# Using Slack's Google Drive integration, but files open in the wrong Google profile

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive, slack

I use 2 different windows to manage each of my Google profiles. When I click through a link from Slack from a colleague sharing a file, it always opens up the wrong profile and I can't view it.

How can I make sure to apply it to my correct profile? I'm always logged into both, but again--separately in different Chrome browser windows.

Comment: According to this Google might treat the **first** account your logged into as default and will use it to open links from Slack. https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1721977?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

I reset (Settings>Advanced>"Restore settings to their original defaults") and relaunched Chrome, then signed in with the account I wanted to use and it's working properly for me now.

Answer (score 0):

In Slack, search for the Google Drive app using the search bar up top. Open the "app" in Slack like you would a conversation and click "About", then click "Configuration." Under "Authentication", you'll see that Google Drive is authenticated to one of your Drive accounts, and I'm guessing it's the one you don't want. Click the "X" next to it. Now go back to the Authentication page and click the green button that says "Authenticate Your Google Drive account" and this will re-link Slack to your preferred Drive account.